# Do not display Save message when isNan value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web project where I have a dropdown menu. Depending on the different selection I can see **"You save"** message. In some scenario it is $1,$2,$3...$500 in other is = empty string " ". When it comes to the empty string it does return **isNaN value**. Is there any way how to check and if **isNAN** do set CSS property to : `display:None;`. Please find link to a simplified version of my code:

[JSBin link to my demo](https://jsbin.com/zopule/edit?html,output)

PS: Please note that I've set on purpose **"You save"** to an empty string

Comment: Please add the _relevant_ code to your question. If that JSBin page disappears your question will be useless.

Comment: If inherently checks for NaN...

Comment: `if (!n instanceof NaN)`?

Comment: @Andy It is a whole CMS page so I can not add the whole code

Comment: @limelights it is crashing when putting the if statement in the change() function

Comment: @Moshe can you please put it in example? I am not sure what you mean by inherently checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function:

```
if (isNaN(youSave)) {
    $(el).hide();
} else {
    $(el).show();
}
```

Some more examples of the function (taken from the Mozilla page):

```
isNaN(NaN);       // true
isNaN(undefined); // true
isNaN({});        // true

isNaN(true);      // false
isNaN(null);      // false
isNaN(37);        // false

// strings
isNaN("37");      // false: "37" is converted to the number 37 which is not NaN
isNaN("37.37");   // false: "37.37" is converted to the number 37.37 which is not NaN
isNaN("");        // false: the empty string is converted to 0 which is not NaN
isNaN(" ");       // false: a string with spaces is converted to 0 which is not NaN

// This is a false positive and the reason why isNaN is not entirely reliable
isNaN("blabla")   // true: "blabla" is converted to a number. 
                  // Parsing this as a number fails and returns NaN
```

There's also a [`Number.isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) introduced in ES2015 that doesn't coerce to numbers, but it is unsupported in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I've seen this but how do we put it into the example I gave as there is two trackings:

1. If element exist
2. onChange()

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.

Assuming you have the value inside of a variable `value`, this could look like:

```
if(value.match(/\$[0-9]+$/)) { ... }
```

Obviously this would not work with different currency symbols or character sets, but you can adapt it as needed.